# Ruby alternative for : Drools (www.drools.org) a business logic integration platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drools

Please suggest a ruby alternative for [drools](http://www.drools.org). It will be better if it also supports integration with rails Active Record.

Comment: What are you looking for in an alternative? What features would you like it to have that drools lacks? Or what features of drools do you want to avoid?

Answer (score 3):

Ruleby is suggested in this slideset http://www.slideshare.net/martincabrera/rules-engine-java-rails